# HTML5 video player no sound in every browser except Safari

Tags: html, google-chrome

The code I have is working in Safari but Opera, Chrome, and Firefox have no sound and I am unable to change the volume because it's just acting as if the video does not have sound. Any help would be great. Thanks

Current Code:

```
 <video width="1000" src="users/Joe_Scotto/videos/1O2bLqQSSe4MGR4f3FBzB0hTqMDRHF/video.mp4" id="main_video" controls="" autoplay=""></video>
```

I've also tried the following which gives the same issue:

```
<video width="1000" id="main_video" controls="" autoplay="">
     <source src="users/Joe_Scotto/videos/1O2bLqQSSe4MGR4f3FBzB0hTqMDRHF/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Perhaps the video file is using an audio codec that is unknown to the browsers, or not present on your system? Have you tried a different video file?

Comment: @Pekka웃 That was the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The codec of the file was causing issues. Changing the file to another codec fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the answer?